# kivy TextInput.select_all is selecting all instances of my subclass

Tags: python, kivy

I'm a learning `kivy` on my own and am trying to create a sublcass of `TextInput` with the custom behavior that, when selected, the contents of the text box are highlighted (so that a user can then begin typing in a new value). I have two questions, one for each attempt.

My first attempt was this:

```py
from datetime import date

# kivy imports
from typing import Text
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.anchorlayout import AnchorLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.properties import (StringProperty)

class MedAssignApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return MainWindow()        
        

class MainWindow(AnchorLayout):
    pass


class TextEntry(TextInput):
    
    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        super().on_touch_down(touch)
        Clock.schedule_once(lambda dt: self.select_all())
```

I then have several instances of `TextEntry` in the `medassign.kv` file:

```
.. other stuff above

    GridLayout:
        cols: 4
        rows: 3

        Label:
            text: 'Date'
    
        DateEntry:

        Label:
            text: 'Shift'
    
        TextEntry:
            text: 'THIS WILL BE A DROPDOWN'

        Label:
            text: 'ST1'
    
        TextEntry:
            text: 'Enter name..'

        Label:
            text: 'ST2'

        TextEntry: 
            text: 'Enter name..'
    
        Label:
            text: 'ST3'
    
        TextEntry:
            text: 'Enter name..'

        Label:
            text: 'ST4'

        TextEntry:
            text: 'Enter name..'

<TextEntry>:
```

However, when I test the application and I click on one of the text fields, all texts in all instances are highlighted. **So my first question is: Does anyone understand why?**

---

My second attempt:

Then I attempted to do it this way (below), which works, but again, I don't know why it works.

```py
# built-in imports
from datetime import date

# kivy imports
from typing import Text
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.anchorlayout import AnchorLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.properties import (StringProperty)

class MedAssignApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return MainWindow()        
        

class MainWindow(AnchorLayout):
    pass


class TextEntry(TextInput):
    pass
```

and `medassign.kv`

```
<TextEntry>:

    TextInput: 
        on_touch_down: Clock.schedule_once(lambda dt: root.select_all())
```

Note: In this second case, if I use `root` it works as I would like. But if I use `self`, it does not work as I would like (it behaves like the first attempt).

My second question: **Can anyone explain why this works with `root`?**

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first version fails because you have not taken into account that all the widgets get the `on_touch_down()` call on every touch down event. It is the responsibility of the instances `on_touch_down()` method to determine if the `touch` is relevant to that instance. The `on_touch_down()` method returns a bool:

> If True, the dispatching of the touch event will stop. If False,
> the event will continue to be dispatched to the rest of the widget
> tree.

So your `on_touch_down()` for every instance applies the `select_all()`. Here is a modified version of `on_touch_down()`:

```
def on_touch_down(self, touch):
    if self.collide_point(*touch.pos):  # check if touch is on this instance
        Clock.schedule_once(lambda dt: self.select_all())
    return super().on_touch_down(touch)  # Let the TextInput handle this touch as normal.
```

Comment: This does the trick, thank you for pointing out that I need to implement the `collide_point` method and return `True` (or else it just keeps cycling through the widgets), although I read all this in the doc, I failed to realize how it should be applied